# Career advice: switching from teaching at 48

Tags: career-development

I am 48 at the moment, teaching in a small university campus. I am deeply dissatisfied with this line of work and desperately want to get out of teaching. I do not know what I can do though, considering my age and background. I have  a doctoral degree in Chemistry and a doctoral degree in Mathematics. However, I do not really have any practical skills. I used to write programs in Fortran.90 for my research in Chemistry long time ago though. I hope to get some advice about what possibilities I may have. I do not want to have a fancy high paying job. In fact, I will not consider working in finance, advertisement, or any similar field the whole purpose of which is to make money. It is extremely important for me to do something useful or at least not harmful. I care deeply about the environment and climate. However, since it may be too late for me to get into this field, I would consider any work, as long as it exists for doing something good. I would also prefer to work from home (at least part of the time) because I live alone with two dogs, and I want to be with them as much time as possible. I like learning, and if it is not too late, I would be glad to enroll somewhere for several months to master a new skill that will give me a job. However, again, I do not really know where to go, and hope someone has a good advice for me. Thank you!

Comment: Train to be a librarian?